# QML TextField: Binding loop detected for property "text"

Tags: javascript, loops, warnings, qml

I'm using QML with JavaScript.
I want to know exactly what the following error means, so I can fix it:

```
QML TextField: Binding loop detected for property "text"
```

Sometimes my app gives me this warning and I don't understand it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Binding loop detected for property `fooProperty` usually means that you have possibly created a *mutually dependent binding* . You should be checking two things :

1. Check if `fooProperty` is binded to some property, which is in turn binds back to `fooProperty` on some condition. (a kind of cyclic dependency)
2. Also, do check if on some condition, `fooProperty` is going into an invalid state.

Comment: Where does fooProperty come from?  I don't see it in the question and I have the same problem with exactly the same message reported.

Comment: I used 'fooProperty' to indicate a general property name. In above example that will translate to property 'text'. https://iq.opengenus.org/foo-bar/

Comment: I have the same problem but I can see no reason for it.

Comment: One general suggestion I can give is to give that property hard coded value at first eg. `text: "Test String"`. Then slowly add other dependencies and see at which point you start getting the error. If you could post this as a new question along with the code, someone could give better answer.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean, can you please clarify?